# WordPress WooCommerce. Вывод кастомного поля в чекаут

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Нужно сделать так, чтобы при добавлении товара там можно было заполнить кастомное поле, и значение этого же поля можно было вывести на странице Checkout. Пробовал добавлять обычные кастомные поля, но их значения не доходили до страницы Checkout. Без плагина.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы добавить кастомное поле для товара, можно использовать хук `woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data`. Пример:

```
<?php
function add_custom_product_field() {
    woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
        'id' => '_custom_field',
        'label' => __( 'Custom Field', 'woocommerce' ),
        'description' => __( 'Enter the custom field here', 'woocommerce' ),
        'desc_tip' => 'true',
        'placeholder' => 'Custom Field',
    ) );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'add_custom_product_field' );
```

Для сохранения значения кастомного поля для товара в БД использовать хук `woocommerce_process_product_meta`:

Пример:

```
function save_custom_product_field( $post_id ) {
    $custom_field = !empty( $_POST['_custom_field'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST['_custom_field'] ) : '';
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_custom_field', $custom_field );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'save_custom_product_field' );
```

Для вывода кастомного поля на странице checkout можно использовать хук `woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item`:

пример:

```
function add_custom_field_to_order_items( $item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order ) {
    $custom_field = get_post_meta( $values['product_id'], '_custom_field', true );
    if ( ! empty( $custom_field ) ) {
        $item->add_meta_data( __( 'Custom Field', 'woocommerce' ), $custom_field );
    }
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'add_custom_field_to_order_items', 10, 4 );
```